# Perl LWP anonymous array reference containing array reference comes across as array with a single element

Tags: arrays, perl, lwp-useragent

I'm having a small issue.  I'm using LWP::useragent and post to another script.  In that script I am performing some logic on a json string and multiple files passed in anonymous array.  Everything was going fine until I attempted to push the multiple files I was passing into an array and pass that as an array reference within the anonymous array.

```
open (IMAGE, "./flower.jpg") or die "$!";
open (IMAGE2, "./fw4.pdf") or die "$!";

$raw_string1 = do{ local $/ = undef; <IMAGE>; };
$raw_string2 = do{ local $/ = undef; <IMAGE2>; };


my @file_array;

push(@file_array, $raw_string1);
push(@file_array, $raw_string2);

my $array_ref = \@file_array;

my $data = [json_string => $json, file_array => $array_ref];
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$res = $ua->request(POST($url, $data));
```

On the catch script I read the params being passed from the anonymous into a hash.  I'm able to access the json string passes without issue like:

```
my $json_post = $params{'json_string'};
```

And then I decode it and do what I wish with it it's all good.  So I figured I could access the array ref like:

```
 my $array_ref = $params{'file_array'};
 my @array = @$array_ref;
```

also tried

```
my @array = @{$array_ref};
```

Comment: Are you writing a client for an existing server, or are you designing the server too? In the former case, what are the specs? In the latter case, what are your requirements?

Comment: The server already exists.  I'm not sure what the specs are, I'm the newbie and don't have access.  I couldn't even muster a decent guess to what the specs might be.

Comment: Then how do you expect to provide what it wants???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only send a stream of *bytes* over a socket. Anything else must be serialized into a stream of bytes and deserialized on the remote end.

Your opted to serialize using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded protocol. It's only capable of serializing key-value pairs of *strings*. Yet you try to pass a *reference*.

You'll need to serialize the contents of the array into a string in a manner expected by the server.

Comment: I would prefer to use JSON.  If I do use JSON, do I have to base64 encode the file?  I did have a version of this working just fine, but I was indeed base64 encoding. I'm told not to do that, and also to pass the parameters as form variables. I believe the reason I'm told not to do it is because we expecting (eventually) a possibility of hundreds of files and in some cases multiple mb pdfs

Comment: Re "do I have to base64 encode the file?", I don't know, do you?

Comment: Well, I'm still doing some research into it.  I appreciate the information you have provided me.  You've been very helpful a number of times now.  From what I understand, to pass the file within the json string, I do have to encode the binary data.  And unfortunately, that isn't an option for me.

Comment: It seems to me I just read "encoding a string using JSON isn't an option because it requires encoding the string". Encoding/serialization is inevitable. A socket can only transmit a stream of bytes, but you want to transmit multiple values.